# Angular Typeahead giving repeated values in the list

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I'm tried typeahead functionality, typeahead suggestions coming but every time its not clearing and (it is appending)showing repeated suggestions in pipe. Please refer attached screenshot. I tried below code,

```
data: any = [];

getTypeaheadData(){
    const param = (document.getElementById('test1') as HTMLInputElement).value;
    if (typeof param !== "undefined") {     
        this.http.get('/api/sampleAPI',{params: {param: param}}).subscribe((response: any) => {      
        this.data.push(...response);          
      })  
    }
}
  
typeaheadVal = (text$: Observable<string>) =>  
  text$
    .debounceTime(200)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .map(term => term.length < 2 ? []
      : this.data.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10));
```

HTML:

```
  <input id="test1" type="text" (keyup)="getTypeaheadData()" class="form-control" [ngbTypeahead]="typeaheadVal" typeahead-no-results="noResults"/>
```

[image: Repeated options]

Answer (score 1):

You push (append operation) the data to the array every time a key is pressed:

```
this.data.push(...response)
```

I think you should have another look at the documentation, get rid of the (keyup) handler, and do something like this example, where a switchMap is used to cancel "in-flight" requests to the service: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/typeahead/http/stackblitz.html